# persisting the search queries in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, session, settings, persist

You `ctrl + F`, put in your rather complex regexp search/replace strings, run the queries, keep working on the code, then the next time eclipse needs a restart all that search/replace dialogue history is gone. Google again the internets for the right regexp syntax, etc. Pretty tedious. Is there a way to make eclipse persist those regexp queries form session to session ?

---

It seems what I am really after is a wayto have more than 10 entries in the search dialog. As the commenters say,Eclipse does persist the search history, just that it is a very short history.
Here is the duplicate that has yet to be addressed properly: [Eclipse: How to increase find/replace history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313258/eclipse-how-to-increase-find-replace-history)

Comment: you might want to look at plugins http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/search%2520history

Comment: The Find/Replace dialog does keeps a history across sessions.

Comment: It persists fine for me too.